# Wrong name for compressed .gz file - Python

Tags: python, gzip

I'm trying to compress a text file into a gzip (.gz) file, in Python, using the following code:

```
import shutil, gzip
text_file = 'C:\\Users\\lenovo-miguel\\Downloads\\python\\text_file.txt'
gz_file = text_file + '.GZ'
with open(text_file, 'rb') as f_in:
    with gzip.open(gz_file, 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

[.GZ file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlYry.png)

The code works, the .gz file is created with the correct name (text_file.txt.GZ), but when you open the .GZ file, the name of the compressed file within it is not 'text_file.txt', it is also'text_file.txt.GZ' (see image).
I need to keep the original name, is there a way to do it?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I ran this on my own box, but just used gunzip from the command line instead of 7zip and it worked as expected. So your code is fine, but 7zip is doing something screwy, there. 
I don't have 7zip to help you out, but I bet if you poke around 7zip's options you'll find something.

Comment: Not seeing a problem. If I use your code, the name in the gzip header is the contents of text_file, not the contents of gz_file.

Comment: Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Perhaps it is something wrong with 7zip, I will look at it...

Comment: Found the problem! used '.gz' instead of '.GZ' and it worked fine!